# Is there any way to get result of the command executed on server in Mina?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn

I am moving my Rails application deploy from Capistrano to Mina. The only thing left to do is writing a task to restart a server. I already did the part to start server, but I can't understand how to stop it.

When I was using Capistrano, I had the following task:

```
desc 'Stop Unicorn'
  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      if test("[ -f #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)} ]")
        execute :kill, capture(:cat, fetch(:unicorn_pid))
      end
    end
  end
```

This, as I understood, firstly runs `test` command to determine whether file exists, and then runs kill command if needed. I understand how to do everything of this in Mina except of how to execute `test` function on server and get its result to do something with it.

Here is what I'm using now,

```
task :restart_server => :environment do
    queue "cd #{deploy_to}/current"
    if File.exists? unicorn_pid
     queue "kill `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
    end
    queue "bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
end
```

but this does not work, and I think I understand why (because the `File.exists` string is executed on client side, not server side).

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided it will be easier to just run `test` function from `queue`, like that:

```
task :restart_server => :environment do
  queue "cd #{deploy_to}/current"

  queue "[ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && kill $(cat #{unicorn_pid})"
  queue "bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
end
```